# Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, counter, bufferedreader

I have been trying to execute this program which many will find a bit useless. Nevertheless I have been getting this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while executing.this program is to find the number of vowels,consonants,special characters etc. and I recently got this error.Please help me. What is this error and how do I remove it from my code .Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
public class numberof {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter string");
String str=br.readLine();
int vowel=0,consonant=0,upcase=0,locase=0,special=0,dig=0;
int l=str.length();
for(int in=1;in<=l;in++){         //This also is being displayed as an error
    char c=str.charAt(in);            //This is the error Line.
    if(c>=65||c<=90||c>=97||c<=123){
        if(c=='a'||c=='A'||c=='e'||c=='E'||c=='o'||c=='O'|c=='u'||c=='U'){
            vowel++;
            if(c>=65 && c<=90){
                upcase++;
                }
            else{
                locase++;
              }
        }
        else{
            consonant++;
            if(c>=65 && c<=90){
                upcase++;
            }
            else{
                locase++;

                    }
                }

            }
    else if(c>=48 && c<=57){
        dig++;
        }
    else{
        special++;
    }

    }
    System.out.println(upcase+" "+locase+" "+vowel+" "+consonant+" "+dig+" "+special);
}
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int in=1;in<=l;in++)
```

should be

```
for(int in=0;in<l;in++)
```

Array index starts from ZERO (`in =0` assuming you want from first element)

EDIT:

`l` is length of `String[]`, let us say 5 split into `a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]`.

If you observe, now you can start from 0 (or) 1 (or) 2, but max you can go upto `a[4]` only, when you use `in <=`, loop will check until a[5] which throws indexoutofBounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you're starting at index 1 and looping while smaller or equal to.

```
for (int in = 1; in <= l; in++) {}
```

This means you'll loop 2 more than you're supposed to. So it should be:

```
for (int in = 0; in < l; in++) {}
```

Array indexes are zero based, so it loops from 0 to length and not from 1 to length.

Another way of writing this is like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {}
```

Most java developers will find this easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to search for vowels in all string, starting from first character? use `for(int in=0; in<l; in++)`